# Fetch data into many dropdown button in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT name FROM student_reg");
foreach ($result as $row){
    echo "<select name='name'>";
    echo "<option value='" . $row->name . "'>" . $row->name . "</option>";
    echo "</select>";
}
?>
```

This code fetch into many dropdown button not in one button.  I want to fetch it into one dropdown button only.  Anyone help me?

Comment: You would only the first row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT name FROM student_reg");
echo "<select name='name'>";
foreach ($result as $row) {
   echo "<option value='" . $row->name . "'>" . $row->name . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're putting a full `<select>` inside each iteration of your foreach loop. You need to move those outside of the loop, and only retain the `<option>` inside it.

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT name FROM student_reg");

echo '<select name="name">';
foreach( $result as $row ){
    printf( '<option name="%s">%s</option>', esc_attr($row->name), $row->name );
}
echo '</select>';
```

WordPress also has some escaping functions like [`esc_attr()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/) that you should be using when you're outputting values into HTML attributes, URLs, etc.